# Trying to correctly format all the dates in RStudio imported from Excel

Tags: r, date

I imported some data from Excel to RStudio (csv file). The data contains date information. The date format I want is month-day-year (e.g. 2-10-16 means February 10th 2016). The problem is that Excel auto-fills 2-10-16 to 2002-10-16, and the problem continues to exist when I imported the data to R. So, my data column contains both the correctly formatted dates (e.g. 2-10-16) and incorrectly formatted dates (e.g. 2002-10-16). Because I have a lot of dates, it is impossible to manually change everything. I have tried to use the this code

`as.Date(data[,1], format="%m-%d-%y")` but it gives me NA for those incorrectly formatted dates (e.g. 2002-10-16). Does anybody know how to make all the dates correctly formatted?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

would you consider to have a consistent date format in excel before importing the data to R?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is likely to change how the data is captured in Excel even if it means storing the dates as strings.  What you're looking for is string manipulation to then convert into a date which could potentially create incorrect data.

This will remove the first two digits and then allow conversion to a date.

```
as.Date(sub('^\\d{2}', '', '2002-10-16'), '%m-%d-%y')
[1] "2016-02-10"
```